# problems combining two scripts to save a google chart on all browsers

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I have been trying to combine two scripts from separate tutorials to convert and save a google chart. The tutorial from here: http://www.battlehorse.net/page/topics/charts/save_google_charts_as_image.html no longer works but I used the suggestions from here to get working ( only works on chrome, not supported by other browsers) so I used this tutorial http://greenethumb.com/article/1429/user-friendly-image-saving-from-the-canvas/ which saves a png image from a canvas and works on all browsers. I am having trouble combining the two and am probably going backwards now lol. here is the non working code, any help would be much appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://canvg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rgbcolor.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvg.googlecode.com/svn-history/r157/trunk/canvg.js"></script>


    <div>   
        <div id="saveexample"></div>

        <canvas id="drawhere_cicles3" style="border: 1px solid #ccc"
            height="350" width="610"></canvas>

    </div>


<script>

  function getImgData(chartContainer) {

    var canvas = document.getElementById('drawhere_cicles3');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');



    var chartArea = chartContainer.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].parentNode;
    var svg = chartArea.innerHTML;
    var doc = chartContainer.ownerDocument;
    var canvas = doc.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.setAttribute('width', chartArea.offsetWidth);
    canvas.setAttribute('height', chartArea.offsetHeight);

    canvas.setAttribute(
        'style',
        'position: absolute; ' +
        'top: ' + (-chartArea.offsetHeight * 2) + 'px;' +
        'left: ' + (-chartArea.offsetWidth * 2) + 'px;');
    doc.body.appendChild(canvas);
    canvg(canvas, svg);
    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    canvas.parentNode.removeChild(canvas);
    return imgData;
  }

  function saveAsImg(chartContainer) {
    var imgData = getImgData(chartContainer);

    // Replacing the mime-type will force the browser to trigger a download
    // rather than displaying the image in the browser window.
    window.location = imgData.replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
  }

function CanvasSaver(url) {

    this.url = url;

    this.savePNG = function(canvas, fname) {
        if(!canvas || !url) return;
        fname = fname || 'picture';

        var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        data = data.substr(data.indexOf(',') + 1).toString();

        var dataInput = document.createElement("input") ;
        dataInput.setAttribute("name", 'imgdata') ;
        dataInput.setAttribute("value", data);

        var nameInput = document.createElement("input") ;
        nameInput.setAttribute("name", 'name') ;
        nameInput.setAttribute("value", fname + '.png');

        var myForm = document.createElement("form");
        myForm.method = 'post';
        myForm.action = url;
        myForm.appendChild(dataInput);
        myForm.appendChild(nameInput);

        document.body.appendChild(myForm) ;
        myForm.submit() ;
        document.body.removeChild(myForm) ;
    };

    this.generateButton = function (label, canvas, fname) {
        var btn = document.createElement('button'), scope = this;
        btn.innerHTML = label;
        btn.style['class'] = 'canvassaver';
        btn.addEventListener('click', function(){scope.savePNG(canvas, fname);}, false);

        document.body.appendChild(btn);

        return btn;
    };
}

  function toImg(chartContainer, imgContainer) { 
    var doc = chartContainer.ownerDocument;
    var img = doc.createElement('img');
    img.src = getImgData(chartContainer);

    while (imgContainer.firstChild) {
      imgContainer.removeChild(imgContainer.firstChild);
    }
    imgContainer.appendChild(img);
  }
</script>

<script>
    var cs = new CanvasSaver('http://greenethumb.com/canvas/lib/saveme.php');
    var canvas = document.getElementById('drawhere_cicles3');
    var btn = cs.generateButton('save an image!', canvas, 'myimage');
    document.getElementById('saveexample').appendChild(btn);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    // Pie chart
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Task');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Hours per Day');
    data.addRows(5);
    data.setValue(0, 0, 'Work');
    data.setValue(0, 1, 11);
    data.setValue(1, 0, 'Eat');
    data.setValue(1, 1, 2);
    data.setValue(2, 0, 'Commute');
    data.setValue(2, 1, 2);
    data.setValue(3, 0, 'Watch TV');
    data.setValue(3, 1, 2);
    data.setValue(4, 0, 'Sleep');
    data.setValue(4, 1, 7);

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('google_visualization_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {width: 450, height: 300, title: 'My Daily Activities'});
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="google_visualization_div"></div>

<button onclick="toImg(document.getElementById('google_visualization_div'), document.getElementById('img_div'));">Convert to image</button>
<button onclick="saveAsImg(document.getElementById('google_visualization_div'));">Save as PNG Image</button>

<hr>
<div id="img_div">
  Image will be placed here
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

here are the two original scripts before I started changing them. This one works only on chrome.

```
   <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://canvg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rgbcolor.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvg.googlecode.com/svn-history/r157/trunk/canvg.js"></script>
<script>
  function getImgData(chartContainer) {
    var chartArea = chartContainer.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].parentNode;
    var svg = chartArea.innerHTML;
    var doc = chartContainer.ownerDocument;
    var canvas = doc.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.setAttribute('width', chartArea.offsetWidth);
    canvas.setAttribute('height', chartArea.offsetHeight);

    canvas.setAttribute(
        'style',
        'position: absolute; ' +
        'top: ' + (-chartArea.offsetHeight * 2) + 'px;' +
        'left: ' + (-chartArea.offsetWidth * 2) + 'px;');
    doc.body.appendChild(canvas);
    canvg(canvas, svg);
    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    canvas.parentNode.removeChild(canvas);
    return imgData;
  }

  function saveAsImg(chartContainer) {
    var imgData = getImgData(chartContainer);

    // Replacing the mime-type will force the browser to trigger a download
    // rather than displaying the image in the browser window.
    window.location = imgData.replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
  }

  function toImg(chartContainer, imgContainer) { 
    var doc = chartContainer.ownerDocument;
    var img = doc.createElement('img');
    img.src = getImgData(chartContainer);

    while (imgContainer.firstChild) {
      imgContainer.removeChild(imgContainer.firstChild);
    }
    imgContainer.appendChild(img);
  }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    // Pie chart
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Task');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Hours per Day');
    data.addRows(5);
    data.setValue(0, 0, 'Work');
    data.setValue(0, 1, 11);
    data.setValue(1, 0, 'Eat');
    data.setValue(1, 1, 2);
    data.setValue(2, 0, 'Commute');
    data.setValue(2, 1, 2);
    data.setValue(3, 0, 'Watch TV');
    data.setValue(3, 1, 2);
    data.setValue(4, 0, 'Sleep');
    data.setValue(4, 1, 7);

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('google_visualization_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {width: 450, height: 300, title: 'My Daily Activities'});
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="google_visualization_div"></div>

<button onclick="saveAsImg(document.getElementById('google_visualization_div'));">Save as PNG Image</button>
<button onclick="toImg(document.getElementById('google_visualization_div'), document.getElementById('img_div'));">Convert to image</button>

<hr>
<div id="img_div">
  Image will be placed here
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

this one works on all browsers

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>CanvasSaver in a project:</p>


        <p>working demo: </p>

    <div>   
        <div id="saveexample"></div>
        <canvas id="drawhere_cicles3" style="border: 1px solid #ccc"
            height="350" width="610"></canvas>

    </div>




    <script>

(function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('drawhere_cicles3');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      // begin custom shape
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(170, 80);
      context.bezierCurveTo(130, 100, 130, 150, 230, 150);
      context.bezierCurveTo(250, 180, 320, 180, 340, 150);
      context.bezierCurveTo(420, 150, 420, 120, 390, 100);
      context.bezierCurveTo(430, 40, 370, 30, 340, 50);
      context.bezierCurveTo(320, 5, 250, 20, 250, 50);
      context.bezierCurveTo(200, 5, 150, 20, 170, 80);

      // complete custom shape
      context.closePath();
      context.lineWidth = 5;
      context.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';
      context.fill();
      context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
      context.stroke();



})();
</script>



    <script>        
function CanvasSaver(url) {
        this.url = url;
        this.savePNG = function(canvas, fname) {
        if(!canvas || !url) return;
        fname = fname || 'picture';
        var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        data = data.substr(data.indexOf(',') + 1).toString();
        var dataInput = document.createElement("input") ;
        dataInput.setAttribute("name", 'imgdata') ;
        dataInput.setAttribute("value", data);
        var nameInput = document.createElement("input") ;
        nameInput.setAttribute("name", 'name') ;
        nameInput.setAttribute("value", fname + '.png');
        var myForm = document.createElement("form");
        myForm.method = 'post';
        myForm.action = url;
        myForm.appendChild(dataInput);
        myForm.appendChild(nameInput);
        document.body.appendChild(myForm) ;
        myForm.submit() ;
        document.body.removeChild(myForm) ;
        };

    this.generateButton = function (label, canvas, fname) {
    var btn = document.createElement('button'), scope = this;
    btn.innerHTML = label;
    btn.style['class'] = 'canvassaver';
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(){scope.savePNG(canvas, fname);}, false);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
    return btn;
    };
}
</script>

<script>
    var cs = new CanvasSaver('/examples/canvassaver/saveme.php');
    var canvas = document.getElementById('drawhere_cicles3');
    var btn = cs.generateButton('save an image!', canvas, 'myimage');
    document.getElementById('saveexample').appendChild(btn);
</script>







</body>

</html>
```

I have tried what was suggested by @asgallant but I have ran into other problems (may be something simple) I added 
    .getElementByTagName('svg')[0].parentNode;
but then the 'save' button vanished. I then added the chartdiv (google_visualization_div) where was suggested and also to the canvas id and the first function but the google chart then vanished. here is the code that i have. Thanks for your help

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://canvg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rgbcolor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://canvg.googlecode.com/svn-history/r157/trunk/canvg.js"></script>
<head>

    <p>Here is an example of implementing the CanvasSaver in a project:</p>
    <div>
        <br>working demo: <br>
        <div id="saveexample">
            <canvas id="google_visualization_div" style="border: 1px solid #ccc"
                height="350" width="610"></canvas>
        </div>

        <script>

(function(){
    var cnvs = document.getElementById('google_visualization_div');
    var cx = cnvs.getContext('2d');

      // begin custom shape
      cx.beginPath();
      cx.moveTo(170, 80);
      cx.bezierCurveTo(130, 100, 130, 150, 230, 150);
      cx.bezierCurveTo(250, 180, 320, 180, 340, 150);
      cx.bezierCurveTo(420, 150, 420, 120, 390, 100);
      cx.bezierCurveTo(430, 40, 370, 30, 340, 50);
      cx.bezierCurveTo(320, 5, 250, 20, 250, 50);
      cx.bezierCurveTo(200, 5, 150, 20, 170, 80);

      // complete custom shape
      cx.closePath();
      cx.lineWidth = 5;
      cx.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';
      cx.fill();
      cx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
      cx.stroke();
})();
</script>


        <br>
        <script>        
function CanvasSaver(url) {
        this.url = url;
        this.savePNG = function(cnvs, fname) {
        if(!cnvs || !url) return;
        fname = fname || 'picture';
        var data = cnvs.toDataURL("image/png");
        data = data.substr(data.indexOf(',') + 1).toString();
        var dataInput = document.createElement("input") ;
        dataInput.setAttribute("name", 'imgdata') ;
        dataInput.setAttribute("value", data);
        var nameInput = document.createElement("input") ;
        nameInput.setAttribute("name", 'name') ;
        nameInput.setAttribute("value", fname + '.png');
        var myForm = document.createElement("form");
        myForm.method = 'post';
        myForm.action = url;
        myForm.appendChild(dataInput);
        myForm.appendChild(nameInput);
        document.body.appendChild(myForm) ;
        myForm.submit() ;
        document.body.removeChild(myForm) ;
        };

    this.generateButton = function (label, cnvs, fname) {
    var btn = document.createElement('button'), scope = this;
    btn.innerHTML = label;
    btn.style['class'] = 'canvassaver';
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(){scope.savePNG(cnvs, fname);}, false);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
    return btn;
    };
}
</script>
        <br>



<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    // Pie chart
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Task');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Hours per Day');
    data.addRows(5);
    data.setValue(0, 0, 'Work');
    data.setValue(0, 1, 11);
    data.setValue(1, 0, 'Eat');
    data.setValue(1, 1, 2);
    data.setValue(2, 0, 'Commute');
    data.setValue(2, 1, 2);
    data.setValue(3, 0, 'Watch TV');
    data.setValue(3, 1, 2);
    data.setValue(4, 0, 'Sleep');
    data.setValue(4, 1, 7);

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('google_visualization_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {width: 450, height: 300, title: 'My Daily Activities'});
  }
</script>
        <script>
var cs = new CanvasSaver('http://greenethumb.com/canvas/lib/saveme.php');
var cnvs = document.getElementById('google_visualization_div').getElementByTagName('svg')[0].parentNode;
var btn = cs.generateButton('save an image!', cnvs, 'myimage');
document.getElementById('saveexample').appendChild(btn);
</script>
</head>


<body><div id="google_visualization_div"></div></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understand you have 2 code one work for google chrome and another for all other browsers how to combine them.(if not you can edit my code  alittle bit to satisfy your needs)
You could try something like this:

```
<?PHP if($browser == "Chrome"){ ?>
<!--HTML Code for Chrome browser-->
<?PHP }else { ?>
<!--Code for other browsers-->
<?PHP } ?>
```

This would help for cross browsers script.

You can get the `$browser` variable with the help of this link:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php#101125

Comment: Basically I want to be able to save a google chart. To do this you have to convert the chart from svg-> png ->canvas and then download the canvas. The first original script the conversion works fine but save function only works on chrome.  The second original script saves a png file on all browsers.  I was trying to use the converting part from one script and add it to the save part from the other. I will look into the $browser now thanks

Comment: @cstu you can try to load the png into the canvas i will try to edit my question to meet your requirements

Comment: @cstu I am sorry bbut i don't understand the codes as it is not commented or explained correctly

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the second, cross-browser solution (and have the server-side code in place), then you don't need anything from the first Chrome-only solution.  Take the example code and modify these lines:

```
var cs = new CanvasSaver('/examples/canvassaver/saveme.php');
var canvas = document.getElementById('drawhere_cicles3');
var btn = cs.generateButton('save an image!', canvas, 'myimage');
document.getElementById('saveexample').appendChild(btn);
```

like this:

```
var cs = new CanvasSaver(saveURL);
var canvas = document.getElementById(chartDiv).getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].parentNode;
var btn = cs.generateButton('save an image!', canvas, 'myimage');
document.getElementById(buttonContainer).appendChild(btn);
```

where `saveURL` is the URL of your saving script, `chartDiv` is the ID of your chart div, and `buttonContainer` is the ID of the container to append the button to.